# Using Fourier Transforms to solve $3u_x + 5u_t = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I'm new to Fourier Transforms and need some help using them to solve equations.
Can someone explain to me how I could use a Fourier Transform to solve an equation like

$3u_x + 5u_t = 0$ with $u(x, 0) = f(x)$?

Comment: How do I do a Fourier transform of the quation in one of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Fourier transform is given by
$$
\tilde u(k,t) = \mathcal F_x[u(x,t)] = \int_{\Bbb R} u(x,t)e^{-ikx}\,dx
$$
Thus, applying [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), we have
$$
\mathcal[F_x u_t(x,t)] = 
\int_{\Bbb R} \frac{\partial }{\partial t}u(x,t)e^{-ikx}\,dx =\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int_{\Bbb R} u(x,t)e^{-ikx}\,dx = \tilde u_t(k,t)
$$
Perhaps you could take it from there.